# How to make a scrolling text contains two or more fonts in css?

Tags: html, css, text, keyframe

```css
.example1 h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
 font-size: 3em;
 color: limegreen;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: left;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);    
 transform:translateX(-50%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(-50%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-150%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%); }
}
@keyframes example1 {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%);       
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
  .example1 h2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
 font-size: 3em;
 color: limegreen;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: left;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);    
 transform:translateX(-50%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(-50%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-150%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%); }
}
@keyframes example1 {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%);       
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Example</title>

<!-- Styles --> 
<style></style>




<!-- HTML -->   
<div class="example1">
<h1>Scrolling text1...Scrolling text2...</h1><h2>Scrolling text3...Scrolling text4...Scrolling text5... </h2>
</div>
```

I'm using keyframe animation to create a scrolling text in CSS, I'm wondering how I could include two or more fonts (in this case h1, h2, h3...) in one line of no warp text.

I tried to duplicate the keyframe animation of h1 to h2, I understand I can achieve the one-line scrolling text of h1 and h2 by adjusting the keyframes but I feel there is a better way to make h2 follows h1 when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Just change behavior default of h1, h2 to `display: inline-block`
and move your `white-space: nowrap` to .example1 which is your container.

hope this will help you...